# Send json data cross-domain with jquery-ajax

Tags: jquery, json

how to send json request to a remote server. Have a look at below script any help? thanks.

$(document).ready(function () 
{

```
         $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "SOMEURL/json/SubmitRequest",
                    data: '{"request":{"RespondentFirstName":"firstname","IsBattery":true,"AccountID":"1","Password":"somepwd!","RespondentEmailAddress":"emailaddress","ID":"id","QuestionnaireID":"Scan","RespondentFamilyName":"lastname"}}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
            crossdomain:true,
                    success: function(msg) 
                    {
                        alert(msg.Data);  
                    },
            error: function(msg) 
                    {
                        alert("Error = " + msg);  
                    }
           });
```

});
getting error message in alert Error = object object

Comment: for getting what is the error use alert("Error = " + JSON.stringify(msg));

Answer (score 0):

an AJAX call doesn't work per default cross domain. However, you can fix this by changing things on both servers.

Take a look at the `JSONP` documentation on this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Another solution is to do a proxy: Do an AJAX call to an own page, and do something with PHP to send the data to the other server

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make AJAX calls cross domian because it breaks the sandbox model of Javascript - a security feature of web browsers.